# Aligning a date picker within a grid

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, gridview, datepicker

I have a SwiftUI view that presents a number of `GridRows` in a `Grid`. Each row has 2 columns, the left column is aligned right, and the right column is aligned left. Each row contains a title (left column) and data field (right column).

`TextFields`, and `Pickers` behave as I expect, aligning to the left side of their column. But the `DatePicker` will only align to the right side of its column.

Things I've tried that didn't work:

- Placing a `Spacer()` after the `DatePicker`
- Putting the `DatePicker` inside  `VStack(alignment: .leading)` within its `GridRow`

Anyone know how to move the DatePicker to align with the rest of the rows on the left?

Below is a view to illustrate

[image]

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var name = ""
    @State var date = Date()
    @State var house = Int()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ScrollView {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Grid(alignment: .leading) {
                        GridRow {
                            Text("Name \(Image(systemName: "person")):")
                                .font(.headline)
                                .gridColumnAlignment(.trailing)
                            TextField("Full name", text: $name)
                                .font(.body)
                                .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                                .padding(.vertical, 5)
                                .background(Color(UIColor.systemBackground))
                                .cornerRadius(8)
                                .gridColumnAlignment(.leading)
                        }
                        GridRow {
                            Text("Birthdate \(Image(systemName: "calendar")):")
                                .font(.headline)
                            DatePicker("", selection: $date, displayedComponents: .date)
                        }
                        GridRow {
                            Text("House \(Image(systemName: "house")):")
                                .font(.headline)
                            Picker("", selection: $house) {
                                Text("Gryffindor").tag(1)
                                Text("Slytherin").tag(2)
                                Text("Ravenclaw").tag(3)
                                Text("Hufflepuff").tag(4)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .padding(10)
                .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                    .fill(Color.gray
                        .gradient
                        .opacity(0.15)))
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
            .navigationTitle("Add Wizard Info")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By inspecting the UI hierarchy, SwiftUI seems to put the date picker inside an `HStack`, consisting of the label (showing an empty string in your case), a `Spacer`, and a `UIViewRepresentable` representing a `UIDatePicker`.

[image]

(Red is the `HStack`, blue is the `Spacer`, black is the `UIViewRepresentable` wrapping a `UIDatePicker`. The label shows "" so is not visible.)

The `Spacer` makes the whole thing "expand" horizontally, pushing the date picker to the right.

Just add [`.fixedSize()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/datepicker) to the `DatePicker`, so that it is at its ideal size.

```
DatePicker("", selection: $date, displayedComponents: .date)
    .fixedSize()
```

Now the `Spacer` won't expand, but note that there is still a bit of spacing:

[image]

That is the default spacing that `HStack` adds between the label and the date picker. If you want to remove that as well, you can take advantage of the fact that `DatePicker` counts as a "labeled content" (not sure if this is guaranteed), and apply your own `.labeledContentStyle`:

```
DatePicker("", selection: $date, displayedComponents: .date)
    .labeledContentStyle(ContentOnlyStyle())
```

```
// this removes the label, and only shows the content (in this case, the date picker)
struct ContentOnlyStyle: LabeledContentStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.content
    }
}
```

Now you don't even need `fixedSize`.

Comment: Thank you! I went looking for how DatePicker was represented in the hierarchy, but couldn’t find the correct documentation on Apple’s developer site. Yours is a very clear explanation. Thanks for mapping it out including the visuals.